# Combining wrapped elements in Scala: Option[Array[Int]]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to combine to arrays that are wrapped in an `Option`:

```
val a = Option(Array(1, 2, 3))
val b = Option(Array(4,5))
val q = for {
  x <- a
  y <- b
} yield x ++ y
```

The problem is that if `b` is `None` it returns `None` even though I'd like to have `a`. And if `a` is `None` the compiler complains that `++` is not a member of `Nothing` (even though I expect to receive `b`). Is this doable with the standard library or do I have to look at semigroups in Cats or Scalaz?

I tried the following in Cats but couldn't get it to work:

```
Semigroup[Option[Array[Int]]].combine(a,b) // === a |+| b
```

It tells me that:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ev: cats.kernel.Semigroup[Option[Array[Int]]]
```

The resulting type should be the same as the types of `a` and `b`.

Comment: i tried with a ++ b directly in repl and it worked for both the cases i.e. a = None or b = None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving the type `Option[C[X]]`, where `C` is some collection type and `X` is the element type of that collection, I came up with:

```
a.fold(b)(x => b.fold(a)(y => Option(x ++ y)))
```

Comment: I added the return type: basically the same as a and b.

Answer (score 3):

```
(a ++ b).flatten.toArray
```

The ++ method is not a part of the Option class, but it works here because of an implicit conversion. If you see the [scala doc for Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option), it says `This member is added by an implicit conversion from Option[A] to Iterable[A] performed by method option2Iterable in scala.Option.`

So, options can be treated as iterables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
val q = a.toList.flatten ++ b.toList.flatten
```